# Incorrect JSON format for Ember Data

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I'm using the latest version of EmberJS and Ember Data.
I have the next JSON data:

```
[{
    "id": 6,
    "name": "First object",
    "vol": 40,
    "description": "bla bla bla",
    "category": "first"
}, {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Second object",
    "vol": 17,
    "description": "Some description",
    "category": "second"
}]
```

And the next model:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  vol: DS.attr('number'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  category: DS.attr('string')
});
```

And I don't understand how to make Ember data works. I have suspicious that ember data expects something like next:

```
[{ 
    model-name {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "First object",
        "vol": 40,
        "description": "bla bla bla",
        "category": "first"
    }
}, { 
    model-name {
        "id": 7,
        "name": "Second object",
        "vol": 17,
        "description": "Some description",
        "category": "second"
    }
}]
```

In console I have a bunch of warnings:

```
WARNING: Encountered "0" in payload, but no model was found for model
name "0" (resolved model name using emdber-drink-
it@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("0"))
WARNING: Encountered "1" in payload, but no model was found for model
name "1" (resolved model name using emdber-drink-
it@serializer:application:.modelNameFromPayloadKey("1"))
```

And more than hundred similar records (that is how many records server returns on request). 
And no data in store.

How can I fix this problem without changing JSON that I receive from server?

Comment: What problem are you having exactly? Errors in the console?

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: what key are you using in the JSON response? If your model is `book`, for example, then you'd want the JSON to be `books: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }]` etc. (where id: 1 and id: 2 represent your records).

Comment: No root key. The server responce example presented in question (first JSON).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to add a custom serializer to add a root key to your JSON data. I haven't tested this but you could try something like:

(using a "book" model as an example)

```
// app/serializers/book.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
    var newPayload = {};
    newPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
    return this._super(store, type, newPayload);
  }
});
```

If this is a problem with the entire API, then you might need to make a custom serializer for the entire application and use the passed-in `type` argument to build the root keys.

Also as a side note, I probably wouldn't use Ember Data if I didn't have control over the API. Unless it follows strict guidelines like jsonapi.org, you're bound to have a few headaches with it.

**EDIT** - changed answer to the suggestion above (using 'type' to build root key).

Comment: Yep, your solution works after a little redaction.                                        `import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
 extractArray: function(store, type, payload) {
     var newPayload = {};
     newPayload[type.modelName] = payload;
     return this._super(store, type, newPayload);
   }
});`

Comment: Glad to hear - I've changed my answer to show the changes that ended up working for you.

Answer (score 5):

From http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html

> In Ember Data a Serializer is used to serialize and deserialize
>   **records when they are transferred in and out of an external source**.
>   This process involves normalizing property names, transforming
>   attribute values and serializing relationships.

At this time there are 4 types of serializers:

- [DS.Serializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Serializer.html)
- [DS.JSONSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html)
- [DS.RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html)
- [DS.JSONAPISerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html)

---

The JSON data you have is plain json.

> JSONSerializer is useful for simpler or legacy backends that may not
>   support the http://jsonapi.org/ spec

So you need **JSONSerializer** which is the most simple solution to consume plain json data.
With ember-cli is pretty easy create a new serializer, for example for a model `book`:

```
ember generate serializer book
```

which will produce something like this:

```
version: 1.13.8
installing serializer
  create app/serializers/book.js
installing serializer-test
  create tests/unit/serializers/book-test.js
```

The previous command will create a serializer of type *RESTSerializer*. (If you dont use ember -cli just create this file at hand)

```
// app/serializers/book.js
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
});
```

and then change `RESTSerializer` by `JSONSerializer`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.JSONSerializer.extend({
    primaryKey: '_id', // useful for mongodb-like data
});
```

I hope you enjoy learning ember as much as I do.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Now I have the next serializer and it works like a charm: https://github.com/drinkit/ember-client/blob/master/app/serializers/application.js

Answer (score 0):

I took another approach and overloaded the 'modelNameFromPayloadKey' method.

If the payload key is of type integer, it will be mapped to the name of the model instead.

```
// app/serializers/<model>.js
import DS from 'ember-data';
import normalizeModelName from "ember-data/-private/system/normalize-model-name";
import {singularize} from "ember-inflector";

export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  model: '<model>',

  modelNameFromPayloadKey(key) {
    // Check whether the key is of type integer
    if (!isNaN(key)) {
      return normalizeModelName(this.get('model'));
    }
    return singularize(normalizeModelName(key));
  },

});
```